# how to use jq and bash to inject a files json array contents while appending

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a .json file which I want to read, take all the contents.. and append it to a json string that's in a bash variable

**input.json**

```
[{
    "maven": {
        "coordinates": "somelib",
        "repo": "somerepo"
    }
},
{
    "maven": {
        "coordinates": "anotherlib",
        "exclusions": ["exclude:this", "*:and-all-that"]
    }
}]
```

**OUR_BIG_JSON** variable

```
{
    "name": "",
    "myarray": [
        {
            "generic": {
                "package": "somepymodule"
            }
        },
        {
            "rcann": {
                "package": "anothermodule==3.0.0"
            }
        }
    ],
```

and a json I want to append to.. it's residing in a variable so we must echo it as we use `jq`

**command attempt**

```
echo "starting..."
inputs_json=`cat input.json`

echo "$inputs_json"
echo "$OUR_BIG_JSON"

OUR_BIG_JSON=$(echo "${OUR_BIG_JSON}" |./jq '.myarray += [{"date":"today"}]')  # This worked..
```

next line fails

```
OUR_BIG_JSON=$(echo "${OUR_BIG_JSON}" |./jq '.myarray += ' $inputs_json)
```

out comes errors when trying to take the `$inputs_json` contents and just pipe it into the variable.. basically append to the JSON in memory..

`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: .myarray += \"$inputs_json\" jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: So you're making JSON by appending strings (??), and want JQ to append some more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `--argjson` option to read in the contents of your shell variable enables you to use it as variable inside the jq filter, too. Your input file can normally be read in via parameter.

```sh
jq --argjson v "${OUR_BIG_JSON}" '…your filter here using $v…' input.json
```

For example:

```sh
jq --argjson v "${OUR_BIG_JSON}" '$v + {myarray: ($v.myarray + .)}' input.json
```

Or by making the input too a variable inside the jq filter

```sh
jq --argjson v "${OUR_BIG_JSON}" '. as $in | $v | .myarray += $in' input.json
```

With the `-n` option you could also reference the input using `input`:

```sh
jq --argjson v "${OUR_BIG_JSON}" -n '$v | .myarray += input' input.json
```

And there's also the options `--argfile` and `--slurpfile` to read in the input file as variable directly...

---

As you have tagged `bash` you could also do it the other way around and use a herestring `<<<` to read in the bash variable as input and then using either `--argfile` or `--slurpfile` to reference the file content through a variable. For instance:

```sh
jq --argfile in input.json '.myarray += $in' <<< "${OUR_BIG_JSON}"
```

Comment: @ikegami My jq (jq-1.6; Linux) does not accept simultaneous input from stdin (coming from `<<<`) **and** from parameter. Same goes for `echo … | jq … input.json` or `echo … | jq … <<< "herestring"` which just ignore stdin.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking of `<( ... )`. But that's not as simple anymore

Comment: @pmf big thanks, the first example worked brilliantly .. wow!